# Change value of <p> based on two <select> choices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change a price by changing option in two `<select>` tags.

For example:

If somebody chooses `Silver 1` in the first `<select>` and `Silver 3` in the second `<select>` then `<p>value</p>` must be `<p>21</p>`.

If the option in the second `<select>` is lower than the option in the first `<select>` it must be `<p>ERROR</p>`

Here is my html:

```html
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="current_tier" id="current_rank">
   <option selected="" value="silver_i">Silver I</option>
   <option value="silver_ii"> Silver II</option>
   <option value="silver_iii">Silver III</option>
   <option value="silver_iv">Silver IV</option>
   <option value="silver_elite">Silver Elite</option>
   <option value="silver_elite_master">Silver Elite Master</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_i">Gold Nova I</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_ii">Gold Nova II</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_iii">Gold Nova III</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_master">Gold Nova Master</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_i">Master Guardian I</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_ii">Master Guardian II</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_elite">Master Guardian Elite</option>
   <option value="distinguished_master_guardian">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
   <option value="legendary_eagle">Legendary Eagle</option>
   <option value="legendary_eagle_master">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
   <option value="supreme_master_first_class">Supreme Master First Class</option>
   <option value="global_elite">Global Elite</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input-sm" name="future_rank" id="order_rank">
   <option selected="" value="silver_ii">Silver II</option>
   <option value="silver_iii">Silver III</option>
   <option value="silver_iv">Silver IV</option>
   <option value="silver_elite">Silver Elite</option>
   <option value="silver_elite_master">Silver Elite Master</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_i">Gold Nova I</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_ii">Gold Nova II</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_iii">Gold Nova III</option>
   <option value="gold_nova_master">Gold Nova Master</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_i">Master Guardian I</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_ii">Master Guardian II</option>
   <option value="master_guardian_elite">Master Guardian Elite</option>
   <option value="distinguished_master_guardian">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
   <option value="legendary_eagle">Legendary Eagle</option>
   <option value="legendary_eagle_master">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
   <option value="supreme_master_first_class">Supreme Master First Class</option>
   <option value="global_elite">Global Elite</option>
</select>

<p id="finalvalue">Final Value</p>
```

Comment: please add what you've tried

Comment: I have no ideas how to do this so I've asked it there.

Comment: bind an onchange event to the selects and detect which one is selected.

Comment: first of all where is the value to be calculated. change your values

Comment: @MaxBelov http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "search and research"

Comment: How the value `21` is obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like that :

```
     <select class="form-control input-sm" name="current_tier" id="current_rank">
                                    <option selected=""value="1">SilverI</option>
                                    <option value="2"> Silver II</option>
                                    <option value="3">Silver III</option>
                                    <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
                                    <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
                                    <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
                                    <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
                                    <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
                                    <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
                                    <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
                                    <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
                                    <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
                                    <option value="13">Master Guardian Elite</option>
                                    <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
                                    <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
                                    <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
                                    <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
                                    <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
                                </select>

            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="future_rank" id="order_rank">
                                    <option selected="" value="2">Silver II</option>
                                    <option value="3">Silver III</option>
                                    <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
                                    <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
                                    <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
                                    <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
                                    <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
                                    <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
                                    <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
                                    <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
                                    <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
                                    <option value="13">Master Guardian Elite</option>
                                    <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
                                    <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
                                    <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
                                    <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
                                    <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
                                </select>

            <p id="finalvalue">Final Value</p>
            <button type="button" id="btnForChosing">Click Me!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var btn = document.getElementById("btnForChosing");
        btn.onclick= function(){
        var finalValue = document.getElementById("finalvalue");      
        var curRank = document.getElementById("current_rank");
        var selectedCurRank= curRank.options[curRank.selectedIndex].value;      
        var orderRank= document.getElementById("order_rank");
        var selectedOrderRank= orderRank.options[orderRank.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selectedCurRank > selectedOrderRank)
            finalValue.innerHTML = "error"
}
    </script>
```

complete your logic for the first case, because i dont under stand the logic you wnat there with the "21"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you derive '21', but this should get you started.  Compare the indexes of the selected options once the second has changed.  If you want to calculate a value for the difference, you'll need to do a basic sum on the values of the selected options and append it to the output instead of 21.

EDIT to assign values to levels and calculate difference on change of second option.  You can adjust the values to whatever numbers are required.

```js
$('#order_rank').on('change', function() {
  $('#finalvalue').html('Final Value: ');
  var current = +$('#current_rank option:selected').val();
  var future = +$('#order_rank option:selected').val()
  if (current <= future) {
    var value = +future - current;
    $('#finalvalue').append(value);
  } else {
    $('#finalvalue').append('ERROR');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="current_tier" id="current_rank">
  <option selected="" value="1">Silver I</option>
  <option value="2">Silver II</option>
  <option value="3">Silver III</option>
  <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
  <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
  <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
  <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
  <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
  <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
  <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
  <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
  <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
  <option value="12">Master Guardian Elite</option>
  <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
  <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
  <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
  <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
  <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input-sm" name="future_rank" id="order_rank">
  <option selected="" value="2">Silver II</option>
  <option value="3">Silver III</option>
  <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
  <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
  <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
  <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
  <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
  <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
  <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
  <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
  <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
  <option value="13">Master Guardian Elite</option>
  <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
  <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
  <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
  <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
  <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
</select>

<p id="finalvalue">Final Value</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

```js
function setOutput(){
  var current_rank  = parseInt($('#current_rank').val()); /*Get current_rank value*/
  var order_rank    = parseInt($('#order_rank').val());   /*Get order_rank value*/

  if (current_rank==order_rank) {
    $('#finalvalue').html(current_rank+' == '+order_rank);
  }else if(current_rank>order_rank){
    $('#finalvalue').html(current_rank+' > '+order_rank);
  }else{
    $('#finalvalue').html(current_rank+' < '+order_rank);
  }
}

$('#current_rank,#order_rank').change(function(){
  setOutput();
});

setOutput();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="current_tier" id="current_rank">
  <option value="1">Silver I</option>
  <option value="2">Silver II</option>
  <option value="3">Silver III</option>
  <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
  <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
  <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
  <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
  <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
  <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
  <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
  <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
  <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
  <option value="13">Master Guardian Elite</option>
  <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
  <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
  <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
  <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
  <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="future_rank" id="order_rank">
  <option value="2">Silver II</option>
  <option value="3">Silver III</option>
  <option value="4">Silver IV</option>
  <option value="5">Silver Elite</option>
  <option value="6">Silver Elite Master</option>
  <option value="7">Gold Nova I</option>
  <option value="8">Gold Nova II</option>
  <option value="9">Gold Nova III</option>
  <option value="10">Gold Nova Master</option>
  <option value="11">Master Guardian I</option>
  <option value="12">Master Guardian II</option>
  <option value="13">Master Guardian Elite</option>
  <option value="14">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
  <option value="15">Legendary Eagle</option>
  <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
  <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
  <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
</select>

<p id="finalvalue">Final Value</p>
```

> **Note:** Now you can check both of them and get the actual result. You can change the condition from `setOutput()` function